# Error handling in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I have this code snippet from the twit module of nodejs:

```
 function tweets() {
        T.get('search/tweets', { q: input, since:'2013-11-11', count: 3 }, function(err, data, response) {
            if (data) {
                  sendMain(data.statuses[0].text);
            }
            else if (err) {
                sendMain(err);
            }
})
    }
```

and everything works fine except the error handling, for example, if I search for `food`, a tweet will pop up, but if I search for `ljfhlsjkdfhsldf` if comes with the error of:

```
              sendMain(data.statuses[0].text);
                                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
    at c:\Users\karim_000\dropbox\main\bot2.js:235:44
    at responseHandler (c:\Users\karim_000\dropbox\main\node_modules\twit\lib\oa
request.js:375:12)
    at passBackControl (c:\Users\karim_000\dropbox\main\node_modules\twit\node_m
odules\oauth\lib\oauth.js:367:11)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (c:\Users\karim_000\dropbox\main\node_modules
\twit\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth.js:386:9)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:943:16
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
    Program node bot2 exited with code 8
```

Why isnt my error handling working? any help? Thanks.

Comment: `data.statuses` exists, but it's an empty array.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine So How can I do some sort of error handling if the array is empty?

Comment: `if (!data.statuses.length) error()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't necessarily an error that is occuring. You are getting the `data` parameter back, however, my guess is that `data` is either `undefined` or `null`.

Have you tried to `console.log('data: ' + data);` to see what is returning? That will tell you for sure what is returning back in that `data` parameter.

Comment: data is undefined, and what I tried to console.log what you said, it returned: `[object Object]`

Comment: Data is shown but when its undefined, nothing shows up as the program exists.